# Having trouble with with preg_replace()

Tags: php

**Sorry about the vague title**. I couldn't find a short way to describe my issue.

I'm using the Twitter API v1.1 to embed a users tweets on a website. As this is just raw text, I'm using this to create URL's:

```
$tweet_text = preg_replace('/(\b(www\.|http\:\/\/)\S+\b)/', "<a target='_blank' href='$1'>$1</a>", $tweet_text);
```

The problem is, I want the text to display without the 'http://'. For example 'http://t.co/wXkHXFs4KR' would simply display as 't.co/wXkHXFs4KR'. I can't think of a way to do this without also removing it from the `href=""`, rather than just the URL between the `<a>` tags.

I appreciate any help,

Oli.

Comment: Can you provide `$tweet_text`, or is that `http://t.co/wXkHXFs4KR`?

Comment: @chris85 `tweet-text` is the full tweet (without links before the `preg-replace()` ), so the `http://t.co/wXkHXFs4KR` (example link) would just be buried somewhere in there, if you see what i mean?

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5c0972b8637443ac5f240cd96fa6cdd2e796ae17

Comment: @chris85 Wow, thanks. I really need to brush up on things like that. If you add it as an answer, I'll mark it as correct. Thanks again.

Comment: Added, I'd also reconsider your check for `www.`. If you pass that into a link it's going to be treated as a relative link. e.g. if your site were `example.com` and you had `<a href="www.google.com">test</a>` on there it would load `example.com/www.google.com` Also note I reduced the capture groups by 1 in my answer below. Maybe I should update my answer to include these notes as well..

Comment: @chris85 I'll be honest, regular expressions baffle me. I've updated my code to use 2 capture groups, although I don't entirely understand what that does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82232/discussion-between-chris85-and-perceptic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should accomplish what you are after

```
echo preg_replace('~\b(www\.|https?://)(\S+)\b~', "<a target='_blank' href='$1$2'>$2</a>", 'http://t.co/wXkHXFs4KR');
```

Here we move your capture groups capture the `http` or `www` then capture the rest of the content.

Output:

```
<a target='_blank' href='http://t.co/wXkHXFs4KR'>t.co/wXkHXFs4KR</a>
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9d5e3e6aca50ce74bcc38594d056d4dde0918fa3